# pvcreate command and setting of extents

Tags: lvm

I am trying to find the way to create phisycal volume with specific range of extents. Vgcreate command has -s option for this(but this command is for groups). I read the man for pvcreate and did not find anything about setting extent size. Is there any way to create phisycal volume with specific number of extents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of physical extent is defined in the volume group creation, not makes sense to do previously with pvcreate as this will only initialize a disk or partition for use with volumes of group and nothing more, the options offered by this command are regarding a physical initialization.

The definition of logical specifications, is managed in the volume group is where the physical extent size is defined.